# XML parser/converter

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

Is there any tool that can parse/conver xml files to this format? 
I have a big bunch of data that needs to be converted. 
Perl XML::Simple and Data::Dumper can do this. Is there any other tool?

From -

```
<create>
   <New>
      <Name>John</Name>
   </New>
</create>
```

To -

```
body =  {
   "create" => { 
      "New" => { "Name" => "John" }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using an XSL transform:-

[Perl XML::XSLT Module](http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/July2000/article156.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

How about good old [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)?

Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>body = {</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>}&#0010;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:text>&#0010;  "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
    <xsl:text>" => {</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>  }&#0010;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[text()]">
    <xsl:text>  "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
    <xsl:text>" => "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 to you as you answered it before me!